# Is there a resource to find free, open wifi hotspots?

Tags: budget, online-resources, wifi

It would be great to know where free, publicly accessible (municipal or otherwise) hotspots are when travelling in foreign cities. Does such a utility exist (website/app etc.)?

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic but I always want such a thing more when I'm travelling than when I'm at home. (Sometimes I want it at home too).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several.

Two of the biggest are:

- http://www.openwifispots.com/
- http://www.wififreespot.com/

Hope that helps!

Another trick I figured out in Kazakhstan is to search for foursquare.com posts about wifi - for example, I was wondering if Astana airport had free wifi, and indeed, https://foursquare.com/venue/2442553 confirmed that it did, and that it is fast! :)

Comment: Good tip about foursquare, works with G+ too (I'm not a foursquare user)

Comment: You don't need to be - I just googled for foursquare and astana airport, it found it for me :)

Comment: @MarkMayo, these websites are almost excusively for the US (for example, there are less then 10 hotspots in as large a city as Rome).

Comment: @evgeny foursquare is pretty worldwide - as I said above, I even used it in Kazakhstan.  It's also 8 years old, so there are probably better resources out there now :/

Answer (score 9):

[FON](http://www.fon.com/) is a community based on wifi sharing. Once you subscribe, you get free access to all other FON wifi hotspots.

Comment: I think I found FON a lot in Japan but don't recall it anywhere else I've been lately.

Answer (score 5):

There are a *lot* of these.

The company that I've found to be dependable is JiWire, which has both the [Global Wi-Fi Finder](http://v4.jiwire.com/search-hotspot-locations.htm) and the [Wi-Fi ZONE Finder](http://wi-fi.jiwire.com). Several other services use theirs as a back-end.

Some others:

- [iPass Hotspot Finder](http://hotspot-finder.ipass.com)
- [Wi-Fi HotSpot List](http://www.wi-fihotspotlist.com)
- [Wi-Fi Everywhere - FON Maps](http://maps.fon.com)
- [Wi-Fi Hotspot Directory](http://www.hotspot-locations.de)
- [Free Hotspot](http://free-hotspot.groopli.com)