# Overview of wireless in airports?

Tags: online-resources, airports, wifi, internet

This summer I travelled by plane a lot. At some airports there was Internet available, but at many I couldn't find any free Internet access. Is there something like an overview available that lists as many airports as possible and indicates if there is free Internet available at these airports?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at least three sites online that cover this:

- [Jaunted](http://www.jaunted.com/maps/Airport-WiFi-Map)
- [Wi-fi Free Spot](http://www.wififreespot.com/airport.html)
- [Airport Hotspot Finder](http://usatoday.jiwire.com/hotspots-hot-spot-airport-directory-browse-by-country.htm)

When I asked a [similar question about Astana airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1304/is-there-wifi-in-astana-airport-kazakhstan), my eventual solution was to use [Foursquare](https://foursquare.com/) - if people have checked in there, there's a good chance they had wifi, or may even mention it.  I found the [relevant page](https://foursquare.com/v/astana-international-airport-tse/4bc3ef0a2a89ef3ba2c7f588) for the airport and voila - lots of mention of the wifi.

Also I nearly marked this as a dupe, but you may want to check out other free wifi links in a [similar question on whether there are listed free wifi hospots around the world](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/is-there-a-resource-to-find-free-open-wifi-hotspots).

Comment: "Airport Hotspot Finder" doesn't look very useful to me. The airports i checked in Germany only lists Telecom as provider, and they are not free but rather expensive. Same with the Airports in Australia, none of them have free wifi - not on this map, and not the last time i had been there. New Zealand section is even worse; "Wellington" is under "Other regions" and Auckland is not there at all.

Comment: It's not a definitive list, and unfortuantely some countries don't do much free wifi.  NZ is horrendous for this, even if you get it (McDs, Coffee Culture) you only get 30 min and 50mb.  That's why I listed it third.

Comment: @iHaveacomputer: It may be that the lists are not missing info but the airports are missing free wifi: **[Do all German airports lack free wifi?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2565/do-all-german-airports-lack-free-wifi)**