# Are there companies that offer worldwide Wi-Fi roaming for a fixed fee?

Tags: airports, hotels, internet, roaming

I am aware of the following related question: [Overview of wireless in airports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2975/overview-of-wireless-in-airports). If it is free it would be nice, but I am willing to pay for my Internet access at airports/hotels. The only problem is that it is often a hassle to get access at these access points. I don't like adding cc details to website when I am at a terminal building of an airport.
Since I am a big fan of [FON](http://www.fon.com), where you share Internet access with fellow members worldwide, I am wondering if there is such "roaming" service for Wi-Fi access. At many airports you see that they offer access to partners.

So, my question is, if there is a company which offers worldwide Wi-Fi roaming services for a fixed fee?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Boingo](http://www.boingo.com/) offers ["worldwide"](http://boingo.jiwire.com/?lang=en) Wi-Fi, with fixed fee, per minute, pay-as-you-go, and package deals. Their [full plan listing is here](http://www.boingo.com/wifi-plans/?lang=en). It starts at $7.95/month for unlimited worldwide access for two mobile devices.

I've not used the service and am not affiliated, but have them bookmarked for my own travels.

Comment: I was going to suggest Boingo as well. I don't use it, but I do see it regularly!

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure whether this is what you're looking for as it does not offer access for a 'fixed' fee, but Skype has a feature called [Skype Access](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/features/allfeatures/skype-wifi/) that allows you to login to paid WiFi hotspots around the world and pay for them using Skype credit in your account. The advantage, of course, is that you don't need to enter your payment details. Still, you'll need to check whether Skype has partners which support this feature in the region you're visiting.

Comment: Skype Access is convenient when needing internet access just to make a quick check online, but the per-minute rates are definitely not optimal -- usually 5 EUR/hour, sometimes more.

Comment: Be aware that Skype Access will often offer you the opportunity to use up your Skype credits on wifi that would otherwise be free. Eg in an airport lounge where you can ask for a code at the desk.